# Translate Button on website - Saving the users language preference

Tags: javascript, html, css

So with my limited JavaScript skills I have created a simple translate button. When you click the button it changes the text on the webpage you are on to either English or Chinese.

How would I go about making these changes stay when someone goes to different webpages or even refreshes the page? I have tried experimenting with the localStorage technique but to no luck.

Here is my JS code for the translate button:

```js
// onclick behavior
$('.lang').click('touchstart', function() {
  var lang = $(this).attr('id'); // obtain language id

  // translate all translatable elements
  $('.tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(aLangKeys[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
  });

});

// preparing language file
var aLangKeys = new Array();

aLangKeys['en'] = new Array();
aLangKeys['ch'] = new Array();

aLangKeys['en']['home'] = 'Home';
aLangKeys['en']['about'] = 'About Us';
aLangKeys['en']['serv'] = 'Services';
aLangKeys['en']['sem'] = 'Search Engine Marketing';
aLangKeys['en']['webdev'] = 'Website Development';

aLangKeys['ch']['home'] = '首页';
aLangKeys['ch']['about'] = '关于我们';
aLangKeys['ch']['serv'] = '服务';
aLangKeys['ch']['sem'] = '谷歌与雅虎推广';
```

For local storage I have added in this right under the var = aLangKeys = new array.

```js
localStorage.setItem("aLangKeys", aLangKeys);
var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("aLangKeys");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include your attempt with using `LocalStorage` as this will give myself and others something to work with rather than having to write a full solution for you. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry! I have added in what I have done for LocalStorage

Answer (score 1):

`LocalStorage` only allows storing strings so you need to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` when getting and setting.

But first you shouldn't be using `new Array()` for non numeric keys. What you are really doing is making an array like object when you do that

Change to:

```
var aLangKeys = {
     en :{},
     ch: {}
}; 
// .... other definitions
```

To set

```
localStorage.setItem("aLangKeys", JSON.stringify(aLangKeys));
```

To get

```
var someVarName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("aLangKeys"));
```